# Need Auto Increment number beginning with Alphabet in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, incremental-backup

Suppose I have a number ED000071, I want the next numbers to be ED000072, ED000073, ED000074.........ED999999, EE000001. Could someone please help me to write a formula for this in Excel?

Comment: Right now, you're not asking us to *help you* write the formula, your asking us to write the formula. What have you tried so far?

Comment: There are "only" 1048576 rows in Excel, this means if you want them all in one column, you can start with `ED000071`, but the sequence will end with `EE048506`

Comment: So far I tried =(LEFT(A1,2)&(RIGHT(A1,6)+1))

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula to change the numbers after the letters:

```
=(LEFT(A1,2)&TEXT((RIGHT(A1,6)+1),"000000"))
```